# How do I implement multiple checklist dropdown menus on a single page, and filter by checked variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is twofold. I have created 2 dropdown menus, with checklists within them. However, when I select the first dropdown menu, the second one expands instead. (When I select the second, it expands as it should.) Additionally, I cannot figure out how to attach my array filter code to the checklists, so that it only pulls data that fits the criteria.

EDIT: I have solved the problem of the dropdown not working, by numbering the subsequent checkLists. The issue of implementing the filters remains, however.

**HTML, CSS and JS**:

```js
'use strict'
let myArray=[
    {site: "", series: "", type: "", dice: "", rps: "", pers: "", species: "", name: ""},{...}
    function filterArr(array, field, value) {
        return array.filter(function (k) {
          return k[field] === value;
        });
      }
      var checkList = document.getElementById('series');
      checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
        if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
          checkList.classList.remove('visible');
        else
          checkList.classList.add('visible');
      }
      var checkList2 = document.getElementById('type');
      checkList2.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
        if (checkList2.classList.contains('visible'))
          checkList2.classList.remove('visible');
        else
          checkList2.classList.add('visible');
      }
      
    function randomFromArray(arr) {
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    }
    document.getElementById("btnSearch").addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=`<img src="${randomFromArray(filterArr(myArray,)).site}">`});
```

```css
:root {
    --blue: #3ee2d5;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --black: #000000;
  }
  * {
    color: var(--fontColor);
    font-family: Georgia;
  }
  
  body {
      background-image:url('https://animal-crossing.com/amiibo/assets/img/pattern-header.png?1456420596');
  }
ul {
    font-family: Georgia;
}

  
.list {
    list-style: square;
  }
  
.light-theme {
    --bg: var(--blue);
    --fontColor: var(--black);
    --btnBg: var(--black);
    --btnFontColor: var(--white);
  }
  
.dark-theme {
    --bg: var(--black);
    --fontColor: var(--white);
    --btnBg: var(--white);
    --btnFontColor: var(--black);
  }
  .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 550px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    color: var(--btnFontColor);
    background-color: var(--btnBg);
  }
  .btn:focus { outline-style: none; }
  .dropdown-check-list {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list .anchor {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
    right: 8px;
    top: 21%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list ul.items {
    padding: 2px;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
    color: #0094ff;
  }
  
  .dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animal Crossing amiibo Card Selector</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainimgbg.css">
</head>
<body class="light-theme">
    <h1>Animal Crossing amiibo Selector</h1>
    <p id="msg">To Do:</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="list">Add exclusion parameters</li>
    </ul>
    <input type=button id="btnSearch" value="Select"/>


<div id="series" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
    <span class="anchor">Series</span>
    <ul class="items">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ser_1" id="ser-1" class="ser-cb" value="ser-1"><label for="ser-1">Series 1</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ser_2" id="ser-2" class="ser-cb" value="ser-2"><label for="ser-2">Series 2</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ser_3" id="ser-3" class="ser-cb" value="ser-3"><label for="ser-3">Series 3</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ser_4" id="ser-4" class="ser-cb" value="ser-4"><label for="ser-4">Series 4</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="ser_wa" id="ser-wa" class="ser-cb" value="ser-wa"><label for="ser-wa">Welcome amiibo</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="type" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
    <span class="anchor">Type</span>
    <ul class="items">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="type_sp" id="type-sp" class="type-cb" value="type-sp"><label for="type-sp">SP/NPC</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="type_vil" id="type-vil" class="type-cb" value="type-vil"><label for="type-vil">Villager</label></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="message"></div>
    </script>
    <script src="gendetailedextrahelpcheck.js"></script>
    <script>alert("This site is a work in progress.")</script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to view the full site.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

My checklist dropdown appears to be formatted correctly on the visual front, and the rest of the code works as intended. My goal is to implement multiple dropdowns (roughly 8).

Comment: You defined `checkList` twice... The second overwrites the first.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that snippet is defining the variable. (I'm very new to coding.) After tinkering with it, I have solved that problem. Thank you!